# Finding points of a curve parallel to another line, in point-slope form?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Due to a work conference, I've fallen a bit behind in my Calculus course and am performing practice problems out of the book to try and catch up on the missed material. One such questions is as follows:

**Find all points on the curve $y=cot (x)$, $0<x<pi$, where the equation of the tangent line is parallel to the line $y=-x$. Put final answer in point-slope form.**

Can anyone elaborate on this? I can visually see on a [graphing calculator](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/?panel-102-graph&data-bounds-xMin=-4.33649289099528&data-bounds-xMax=5.66350710900472&data-bounds-yMin=-2.6609110629067527&data-bounds-yMax=4.619088937093247&data-equations-0=%22y%3Dcot(x)%22&data-equations-1=%22y%3D-x%22&data-rand=undefined&data-hideGrid=false) the lines formed by $cot(x)$ and $(-x)$. Being between $0<x<pi$ (pi being 3.14...) I assume then I'm looking at the $cot(x)$ line falling just right of the origin?

Comment: What does it mean for a line to be parallel to another line? Hint: think in terms of the slope.

Comment: Right, I understand the meaning of parallel, but not how to find what is being asked of me (other than just the visual).

Comment: Humor me. Tell me what you think parallel means in terms of the slope. I am not trying to insult you; I am trying to help you solve this problem on your own.

Comment: parallel in terms of slope means having the same slope. slope of $(-1)$ will be the same for parallel points.

Comment: Yes, and then I was going to ask you how you find the slope of the tangent to the curve $y=\cot x$ but the rest of the story seems to be spelled out below.

Comment: I'm totally lost on the below. Where did $-csc^2(x)=-1$ come from when looking at $1+cos(x)$??

Comment: Take the derivative of $\cot x$ and set it equal to $-1$. Remember, you only need consider $x$ values between $0$ and $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $y'(x)=-\csc^2(x)$, and since this is the slope of the tangent line at the point $(x,y(x))$ and parallel lines have the same slopes, we have to solve the equation

$$-\csc^2(x) = -1$$

That's equivalent to $\sin^2(x) = 1$, so we need to find all values of $x$ that give $\sin(x) = 1$ or $\sin(x) = -1$. These have the form $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. For all these points, $\cos(x) = 0$, so $y=\cot(x)=0$.

Finally, the equations of the tangent lines in point-slope form are given by

$$y-0=-\Bigg(x-\Bigg(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\Bigg)\Bigg), k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: How do you jump from $sin(x)=1|sin(x)=-1$ to knowing these have from $x=pi/2 + k(pi)$? Or the part of $cos(x)=0, thus y=cot(x)=0$?

Comment: $\sin(x) = 1$ for $x = \frac{pi}{2} + 2k\pi$ and $\sin(x)=-1$ for $x=\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi$. Putting these two together gives what I wrote in the answer (drawing a picture of the circle might help). For the other part, $\cot(x) = \frac{cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$, so $\cot(x)=0$ whenever $\cos(x)=0$.